# Ownership Chaining not working between two schemas in the same database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-schema

I have a database on SQL Server 2008 R2 that has two schemas, the default dbo and another one called Webapps, and both schemas are owned by dbo.

I created a view in the Webapps schema (Webapps.getInventory) that just does a simple select from dbo.Inventory. Then I created a user called Webuser that has `SELECT` permission to the Webapps schema.

Webuser can login and see the Webapps.getInventory view, but when it tries to select from it this error comes up:

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Inventory', database 'Database', schema 'dbo'.

I was thinking that since both schemas are owned by dbo, ownership chaining would allow the query to execute.  The only way I seem to be able to get it to work is give Webuser permissions on dbo, or add it to the db_datareader role for the whole database.  To me that seems to defeat the purpose of trying to separate things out into the Webapps schema if the user has to have read ability to everything else in the database.

So, am I overlooking something in my setup? Or is it correct that Webuser must have permission on both schemas in order for this view to work?

Comment: Well, yes, if the underlying table is dbo.Inventory, the user will need permission to select from that table in the dbo schema.  Why does that defeat the purpose of separating things out into a Webapps schema?  If you want to, you can always create a separate table in the Webapps schema called Webapps.Inventory.  But if you want this particular user to be able to select from a table in the dbo schema, then they will need permissions in the dbo schema.

Comment: But everything I've read on ownership chaining says that as long as the two schemas have the same owner, the user should only have to have permissions on the schema it is calling.  So the user calls the Webapps.Inventory view, which is able to call the dbo.Inventory table (because Webapps and DBO are both owned by DBO).  In fact, in theory the user could actually be denied SELECT on DBO, but should still be able to pull results via Webapps.Inventory.  It's just odd that everything I read says it should work, but it doesn't for me.

Comment: Aha - an object permissions issue, and you can in fact jump schemas. I learned something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eric I think you are "jumping" over a step in the ownership chain...
Have (another) look at this article: [Ownership Chains](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) Here is a snippet "Ownership chaining enables managing access to multiple objects, such as multiple tables, by setting permissions on one object, such as a view."

The chaining doesn't care that both schemas are owned by dbo, but rather that each login/user has appropriate permissions on object. So if you have a table owned by dbo that is included in a view where you have given select access to the webapps schema, then the users with access should have access to the table. The ownership chain isn't checked deeper than the fact that they can select against the view, no need to evaluate if they can select against the table.

So long story short, if you wrap the dbo.table in a view where webapps has select permissions then you should be good.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks!  I thought that was what I was doing.  My Webapps schema has a view that wraps dbo.Inventory.  Webuser has SELECT permissions on that view.  When Webuser calls the view it errors, saying permission was denied on object 'inventory', schema 'dbo'.

Comment: @Eric I think that in order to make ownership chaining workable the **called object (the Webapps.getInventory view)** must be owned by **dbo** too. Check this using `SELECT 
    so.[name] AS [Object]
  , sch.[name] AS [Schema]
  , USER_NAME(COALESCE(so.[principal_id], sch.[principal_id])) AS [Owner]
  , type_desc AS [ObjectType]
FROM sys.objects so
  JOIN sys.schemas sch
    ON so.[schema_id] = sch.[schema_id]
WHERE [type] IN ('U', 'P');`

Answer (score 0):

Another reason that cross-schema ownership chaining may break is if the schema owners were recently changed, e.g. setting them to the same owner specifically in order to use ownership chaining. **You may need to drop and recreate the views** (and add the permissions back) before it will work.

SQL Server caches various properties of views, and I saw a case where this caching appeared to be causing SQL Server to not realize that an object accessed by the view actually did have the same owner at that point. It gave a "permission denied" error on the object accessed by the view.  Dropping and recreating the view fixed the problem. Rebooting the database server might have also fixed it, but that was not an option at the time.

SQL Server also allows individual objects to have specific owners different from the schema owner, and I confirmed that neither the view nor the accessed object had a separate owner set. I saw this in SQL Server 2012. Not sure if it's been fixed in newer versions.